# Angular formControl how to handle array property

Tags: angular, forms

I have the following Angular form:

```
<form [formGroup]="futureForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveFuture(futureForm.value)">
    // ...

    <div class="row" *ngFor="let value of atr.values" >
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="{{value.prop1}}"
                 formControlName="values.prop1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="{{value.prop2}}"
                 formControlName="values.prop2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="{{value.prop3}}"
                 formControlName="values.prop3">
        </div>
    </div>

    // ...
</form>
```

Note that formGroup name is `futureForm` and on submit we are calling `onSaveFuture`.

My problem is that `atr.values`, which is being looped through with `*ngFor`, is an array. I want `futureForm.value` (the parameter that gets passed to the `saveFuture` function) to contain the array with value objects in it when the form gets submitted.

The following problem occurs. The console says this:

> Cannot find control with name: 'values.prop1'

Also on submit, i am not getting the array that i want. `atr.values` is not even an array, but a single object.

How do i make it so that my different inputs will correspond to their respective `atr.values` entry so that the value is shown and also passed as an array to the `onSaveFuture` function?

My component looks like this:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  atr: IAtr;
  futureForm;

    // constructor..

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // ..
        this.futureForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          // ..
          values: this.atr.values,
        });
    }

    // onSaveFuture..
}
```

Is there something i am missing, or do i need to use something other than formControlName??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're data is an array, you need a `FormArray` which is a little more complex than normal form groups.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // ..
    this.futureForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      // ..
      // initialize with array of groups
      values: this.formBuilder.array(this.atr.values.map(v => this.getValueGroup(v))),
    });

}

get valuesForm() {
  return this.futureForm.get('values') as FormArray
}

private getValueGroup(v?) {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
     // value group properties
     prop1: [v ? v.prop1 : ''] // something like this, initialize to prop value or default, add validators or whatever
  })
}

addValue(v?) {
  // use this to add new values
  const vg = this.getValueGroup(v);
  this.valuesForm.push(vg);
}

removeValue(index: number) {
  // remove values
  this.valuesForm.removeAt(index);
}
```

then in template, things will look different too:

```
<ng-container formGroupName="values"> <!-- need some wrapper to build the path to the array... still uses formGroupName even though array --> 
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let ctrl of valuesForm.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i"> <!-- iterate the controls,  group names are the index -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                 formControlName="prop1"> <!-- just the property name, don't explicitly assign value -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                 formControlName="prop2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                 formControlName="prop3">
        </div>
    </div>
<ng-container>
```